# SQL: Finding middle result between dates and Criteria

Tags: sql, date, netezza

I have to find and tag customers who meet the following criteria but I'm struggling to come up with a way to do it in SQL rather than manually in Excel.

The customer must meet this criteria:

1. Stay in Motel A
2. Stay in Motel B within 1 day of leaving A  (Motel B cannot > 30 days)
3. Go back to Motel A within 1 day of leaving B

Start and End Dates must be the same or +1 day to account for billing lag

We want to tag sale ID # (unique for all) for Motel B.

```
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Cus ID | Sale ID | Motel ID |   SDate:   |   EDate:   |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      1 |    1234 |  MA      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
|      1 |    1435 |  MB      | 2017-01-07 | 2017-01-10 |
|      1 |    1562 |  MA      | 2017-01-10 | 2017-01-15 |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Here we would tag Sale ID: 1435 as a valid criteria

```
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Cus ID | Sale ID | Motel ID |   SDate:   |   EDate:   |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      2 |    3456 |  MA      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
|      2 |    3588 |  MB      | 2017-01-09 | 2017-02-15 |
|      2 |    3648 |  MA      | 2017-02-16 | 2017-02-17 |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

This one fails since #3588 exceeds 30 days, and should not be tagged

```
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Cus ID | Sale ID | Motel ID |   SDate:   |   EDate:   |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      1 |    1234 |  MA      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
|      1 |    1435 |  MB      | 2017-01-07 | 2017-01-10 |
|      1 |    1562 |  MA      | 2017-01-10 | 2017-01-15 |
|      1 |    1580 |  MB      | 2017-01-15 | 2017-01-20 |
|      1 |    1590 |  MA      | 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-22 |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

This one would tag 2 #1435, and #1580

```
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Cus ID | Sale ID | Motel ID |   SDate:   |   EDate:   |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      1 |    4555 |  MA      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
|      1 |    4803 |  MB      | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-10 |
|      1 |    5238 |  MA      | 2017-01-10 | 2017-01-15 |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

This one fails since there is a 2 gap date between #4555 and #4803, and should not be tagged

Any advice or help is much appreciated.  I can do this manually via Excel but to do so over millions or records is way too time consuming.

I'm using Aginity Netezza SQL if that matters at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()` to get the "previous" and "next" stays.  I think your conditions turn into the following `where` conditions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(edate) over (partition by cusid order by sdate) as prev_edate,
             lead(sdate) over (partition by cusid order by sdate) as next_sdate,
             lag(motelid) over (partition by cusid order by sdate) as prev_motelid,
             lead(motelid) over (partition by cusid order by sdate) as next_motelid
      from t
     ) t
where prev_motelid = next_motelid and
      prev_edate in (sdate, sdate - interval '1 day') and
      next_sdate in (edate, edate + interval '1 day');
```

I don't know what you mean by "(Motel B cannot > 30 days)".  If that is the duration in the middle Motel, then this is easily added into the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried this code on:  MA: 20160322--20160327 and MB: 20160327--20160331 and MA: 20160331--20160407, it returned the MA: 20160331--20160407.  The results should return only MB when the criteria is met.

Comment: @Snoobie . . . There must be another record afterwards for "A".

Comment: I tweaked your where clause and got it to work. Thank you so much for your guidance! You saved me hours of work!